# big O notation of isset operation

Tags: php, big-o

Having an array:

```
$array = (..., 'name' => 'foo', 'age' => 69, 'address' => 'bar');
```

I'll use the operation:

```
if(isset($array['address'])) { //Do something... }
```

Is the big O notation would be O(n)? How does the isset() works behind the scenes?

Comment: An array is a hashmap, so it's O(1) as all PHP has to do is generate the hash and see if there's any value at that hash entrypoint.... it doesn't have to iterate through the array (which would be described as O(n) rather than O(3) anyway)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! if it was a var like $var = 2, how does it check in the memory if it exist?

Comment: It's a simple O(1) again.... the variable is either defined or it isn't.... and you can see exactly how it works behind the scenes by checking in the PHP source code

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Mark Baker, it's O(1). However, take note that this is only in the average case.

As a matter of fact, it is still possible for a search operation in hash maps to take O(n) time due to hash collisions no matter how well you implement a hash map (chaining, probing, etc).

Nonetheless, that does not mean that hash tables are bad in practice. In fact, Big O is simply something that is often used to describe the worst-case scenario of an algorithm.